# Logic Error when trying to output a decrypted string from an encrypted string in Visual Studios C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, encryption, visual-c++, logic

my program takes a encrypted string into a class function EncryptedString(string str). It seems like everything is being outputted correctly aside from when I try to call a get function to get the decrypted string I am met with "ZZZZZZZZ". The Program takes a phrase or sentence, encrypts the sentence and deletes any illegal characters, then decrypts it and outputs the decrypted result. I am putting in "Hello World!" and it deletes the ! just fine. The space is supposed to kept however it too is also turned into a Z.

- Input: Hello World!
- Expected result: Hello World
- Output: ZZZZZZZZZZZ

I am also having a problem with the output of my encryption. I am also to output the encrypted version of the phrase. However when I output it, nothing is being put out.

- Input: Hello World!
- Expected result: Ifmmp Xpsme
- Output is blank.

Here is the code for the entire EncryptedString.cpp file. Thank you to whoever helps me with this problem and if you need to see the main.cpp file or the header file for that declares the functions I will be happy to provide, it is just I do not think they are not necessary with this error. However I could be wrong.

```
#include "EncryptedString.h"


string decrypted;

EncryptedString::EncryptedString(string str)
{
    string enCrypt = str;
    set(enCrypt);

}



void EncryptedString::set(string str)
{
    char chBase = 'A';


    string enCry = str;
    for (int i = 0; i < enCry.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = enCry[i];

        if ((enCry[i] < chBase || (enCry[i] > chBase + 25 && enCry[i] <  tolower(chBase)) || enCry[i] > tolower(chBase + 25)) && enCry[i] != ' ')
        {
            enCry.erase(enCry.begin() + i);
        }
        else
        {
            if (enCry[i] = chBase + 25)
            {
                enCry[i] = 'A';
            }
            else if (enCry[i] = tolower(chBase) + 25)
            {
                enCry[i] = 'a';
            }
            else if (enCry[i] = ' ')
            {
                enCry[i] = ' ';
            }
            else
            {
                enCry[i] = ch + 1;
            }

        }


    }

    EncryptedString::encryption == enCry;
    string decrypt = enCry;

    for (int i = 0; i < decrypt.length(); i++)
    {
        char ch = decrypt[i];

        if (decrypt[i] = 'A')
        {
            decrypt[i] = 'Z';
        }
        else if (decrypt[i] = 'a')
        {
            decrypt[i] = 'z';
        }
        else if (decrypt[i] = ' ')
        {
            decrypt[i] = ' ';
        }
        else
        {
            decrypt[i] = ch - 1;
        }
    }

    decrypted = decrypt;
}

const string EncryptedString::get()
{

    return decrypted;
}

const string EncryptedString::getEncrypted()
{
    return EncryptedString::encryption;
}
```

Comment: `if (enCry[i] = chBase + 25)` -- Using `=` is not the way you test for equality in C++

Comment: Thank you for that. It's been a bit since I've used C++. I just changed it to ==, I've also deleted an extra '=' at EncryptedString::encryption = enCry;  However, now only get Encrypted is displaying but it is displaying the decrypted version of the string. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Anchara, please avoid making a moving target, by either changing the question or by adding more questions in comments. If you have a new question after getting help with the initial one, then please make a new question on the new problem.

Comment: Nevermind, it works! I added an extra equal signs inside the if statements on accident. Thank you @PaulMcKenzie for helping me out!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Would you like to make an answer? I think the initial question is answered.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tip @Yunnosch So would that mean I just edit my post, to format into the question? Or make a new thread entirely.

Comment: What do you mean by "format into the question?".

Comment: Rewrite the program so it fits with the corrections, and then asking a new question via deleting the old text of the post and writing it as a new question.

Comment: That would turn the question into a moving target, which is not appreciated here. Especially now that there is an answer to the initial question. Please ask in a new question about the next problem which arises after fixing the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the wrong operator for equality comparisons:

```
if (enCry[i] = chBase + 25)
```

In C++, you use `==` to compare for equality, not `=`.  The above line should be:

```
if (enCry[i] == chBase + 25)
```

You make similar errors in several other lines in your program.  Correct those errors and rerun your program.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it. Thank you for help